# plotting means in a horizontal bar with a vertical line

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

| ID | score1 | score 2 | score 3 | score 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 300 | 400 | -200 |
| 2 | 250 | -310 | -470 | -200 |
| 3 | 210 | 400 | 480 | -200 |
| 4 | 220 | -10 | -400 | -200 |
| 5 | 150 | -50 | 400 | -200 |

I am new to R, I want to make a graph that presents the mean of each score.
whereas, the scores are lined in the Y axis, and there is a vertical line which represents the 0.
every score mean above zero a horizontal bar appears from the central to the right.
every score mean below zero a horizonal bar appears from the central to the left.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result by first converting your dataset to long format and by computing the means per score afterwards. After these data wrangling steps you could plot the means using `ggplot2` via `geom_col` and add a vertical zero line using `geom_vline`:

```r
df <- data.frame(
          ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
      score1 = c(200L, 250L, 210L, 220L, 150L),
     score.2 = c(300L, -310L, 400L, -10L, -50L),
     score.3 = c(400L, -470L, 480L, -400L, 400L),
     score.4 = c(-200L, -200L, -200L, -200L, -200L)
)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- df |> 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "score") |> 
  group_by(score) |> 
  summarise(value = mean(value))

ggplot(df1, aes(value, score)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

**EDIT** To label the bars you could use `geom_text`. Tricky part is to align the labels. To this end I make use of an `ifelse` to right align (hjust = 1) the labels in case of a positive mean and left align (hjust = 0) in case of a negative mean. Actually I did 1.1 and -.1 to add some padding between the label and the bar. The axis labels could be set via the `labels` argument of the scale, in your case it is `scale_y_discrete`. Personally I prefer to use a named vector which assign labels to categories in the data.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(value, score)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value, hjust = ifelse(value > 0, 1.1, -.1)), color = "white") +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = c("score1" = "Test1", "score.2" = "Test2", "score.3" = "Test3", "score.4" = "Test4"))
```

[image]

Comment: amazing graph sir, thanks
1) How can I change the name of the score - to present the label (real name of the test)?
2) how can I present the mean in that box? so its easier to read it

Comment: Hi @SariKatish . I just made an edit with one approach to add your labels.

Answer (score 1):

Similar approach with stefan's but slightly different choice of functions:

1. The data:

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, score1 = c(200L, 250L, 210L, 220L, 150L
), score2 = c(300L, -310L, 400L, -10L, -50L), score3 = c(400L, 
-470L, 480L, -400L, 400L), score4 = c(-200L, -200L, -200L, -200L, 
-200L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

2. The chain of functions

```
dat %>% 
  select(-ID) %>% 
  map_df(mean) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "score", values_to = "means") %>%
  ggplot() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_col(aes(x = score, y = means))
```

3. The result

[image]

In case you want to change the labels on the tick marks ("score 1", "score2", etc) to other labels, you can use `scale_x_discrete`.
In addition, in case you want to show the numeric value on top of each bar, you can use `geom_text` with `hjust` to adjust the label positions.

For example :

```
dat %>% 
  select(-ID) %>% 
  map_df(mean) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "score", values_to = "means") %>%
  ggplot() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_col(aes(x = score, y = means)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Test A", "Test B", "Test C", "Test D")) +
  geom_text(aes(x = score, y = means, label = means), 
            hjust = c(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.1))
```

[image]

Comment: amazing graph sir, thanks 1) How can I change the name of the score - to present the label (real name of the test)? 2) how can I present the mean in that box? so its easier to read it

Comment: As for your first question, please check my edited answer. For your 2nd question, sorry I don't understand what you mean by `present the mean in that box`.

Comment: Thanks your answer worked wonderfully, 
I just want to present the mean for every test in the bar charts so its easier to see the mean

Comment: Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Hello @Abdur , this code that you gave me for the graph worked wonderfully. However, now I am trying to run it and it doesn't work - I get this message:
"Error in select(., "ID") : unused argument ("ID")" 
Do you know what can I do to make it work again?

Comment: Could you show the full code that you used? Because my code used `select(-ID)` and not `select("ID")` so I don't understand the error message that you got.